# Polymorphic associations : which migration file must I change?

Tags: polymorphic-associations, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models : User and Product.
I want to add a third model, Location.

I've created the Location model with : `rails generate model Location address:string`

Accordingly to the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations), I modify the **app/models/model.rb**

```rb
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :localizable, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :location, as: :localizable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :location, as: :localizable
end
```

And then I add the foreign_key and an index in my Location migration file :

```rb
class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :locations do |t|
      t.string :address
      t.integer :localizable_id
      t.string :localizable_type

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :locations, [:localizable_id, :localizable_type]
  end
end
```

But it doesn't work as I thought. When I use the rails console, I can't get a `user.location` or a `product.location`. It sends me back the following message :

```rb
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: locations.localizable_id: SELECT  "locations".* FROM "locations"  WHERE "locations"."localizable_id" = ? AND "locations"."localizable_type" = ?  ORDER BY "locations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

Do I must add `t.integer :location_id` to both user and product migration file ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're doing here is to setup a `has_many` <--> `belongs_to` environment.

If you really want a a `has_one` then you just have to add a foreign key on your `User` and `Product` models. No need to use a polymorphic model if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But I'm still curious about the problem I met.